# Why is Geschwister gender neutral and not Gebrüder?

Tags: etymology, gender

[What is the difference between “Brüder” and “Gebrüder”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31887/what-is-the-difference-between-br%C3%BCder-and-gebr%C3%BCder) asks about the difference between the words "Brüder" and "Gebrüder".

There is the gender neutral Geschwister for brothers and sisters. Geschwister is a generic feminine gender (generisches Femininum, based on Schwester). In German the [Generisches Maskulinum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum) is more common.

Is there a reason, why Geschwister became the generic expression for sisters and brothers and not [Gebrüder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebr%C3%BCder)?

The [Ngram for Bruder, Brüder, Schwester(n), Gebrüder and Geschwister](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Br%C3%BCder%2CGebr%C3%BCder%2CSchwestern%2CGeschwister%2CBruder%2C%20Schwester&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBr%C3%BCder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGebr%C3%BCder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSchwestern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGeschwister%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBruder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSchwester%3B%2Cc0) is:
[image]

Comment: I think it might be interesting to see whether there is a connection to "verschwistert" und "verbrüdert".

Comment: @knut You seem to be assuming *Geschwister* is feminine. It isn't.

Comment: @tofro. The question seems to confuse grammatical gender (genus) with natural gender (sexus). Gebrüder and Geschwister are both used only in the plural. Consequently neither has a recognizable grammatical gender.

Comment: @fdb Geschwister is *neuter*, according to Duden and other dictionaries, and can (other than *Gebrüder*) very well be used in singular: "Das jüngere Geschwister ging noch einmal aus dem Haus"

Comment: @tofro. In the singular it is very rare. By the way, in OHG  giswester is feminine.

Comment: The question is acutally: Why is "Geschwister" (=all sisters) used for a mixed group and not "Gebrüder" (= all brothers), when usually in Germany the Generisches Maskulinum (Gebrüder) is used for mixed groups? Right?

Answer (score 10):

Both **[gibruoder](http://dwds.de/wb/Gebr%C3%BCder)**, and  **[giswester](http://dwds.de/wb/Geschwister)** were known in Old High German, when they indeed had a gender specific meaning, restricted to brothers or sisters only.

Starting from Middle High German we also find references for **geswister** used for children of same parents to include both, brothers and sisters.

Little is known for the specific reason why boys were included in *Geschwister* but not girls in *Gebrüder* but it may have something to do with the usage of these terms.

Even in Old High German the term **giswester** was exclusively used for a close family-like relationship (of girls) whereas **gibruoder** was always more than just a family relationship as it also indicates heritage. Apparently this was important in this rather patriarchal society.

> wir von gots gnaden Ernst, des heil. rom. reichs erzmarschalg, kurfurste, und Albrecht **gebruder**, herzogen zu Sachsen <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG03033#XGG03033)</sup>

This may also be why from the 19th Century until today *Gebrüder* is used exclusively for business relationships (between male brothers).

Comment: Agree with most what you say, but not necessarily the last sentence: There are quite some 20st century standing expressions from *Gebrüder Wright* to *Gebrüder Blattschuss* that do not necessarily relate to business relationship. (And I **very much** like "male brothers", especially in this context...)

Comment: @tofro: Well, *Gebrüder Blattschuss* seems to be a band, which can be called a business entity. As for *Gebrüder Wright*, aren't they more commonly known as *(die) Brüder Wright* in German? I cannot remember any occasion where I heard them referred to as *Gebrüder Wright*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If I could add an *ngrams* graph to a comment, I'd show you both expressions are used nearly equally often, with a slight headstart to "Gebrüder". And a "band" as a business entity? *Rolling Stones Ltd.* Get real...

Comment: @tofro: Not sure what you mean. Of course, at least professional bands play to generate revenue and act as a little company, just like a small hypothetical grocery store named *Gebrüder Müller und Meier*. That's what I understand by "business entity".

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is simply that language doesn't strictly follow logic all the time (after all, the rules are defined by *watching* the language as it evolves, not the other way round).

In case the generic masculine ("Generisches Maskulinum") in German is already occupied with specific meaning - here: "Assortment of brothers" - Language needs to somehow work around this. In this specific case, it has chosen to do that that by employing the sisters. Apparently, there was simply a higher need during language evolution for a word denominating all the brothers in a family than for all siblings, so the brothers occupied that vacancy first.

EDIT: Dictionaries (and Takkat's answer) say that "Geschwister" used to denominate the sisters of a family originally - This doesn't change much of the argumentation, though: Language just considered the assortment of all siblings more important to have a name and thus re-used the sisters.

BTW: The generic for "Krankenschwester" is **not** *Krankenbruder*, thus somehow breaking the same "rule", just for other (historical) reasons.

Comment: I think, Geschwister was already occupied with a specific meaning, too: "mittelhochdeutsch geswister, althochdeutsch giswestar, eigentlich = Gesamtheit der Schwestern" (Duden). And I think "Krankenschwestern" is equal to "Ordensschwestern", there have just never been male ones in the group.

Comment: @Iris Note there are indeed "Ordensbrüder" and "Krankenpfleger"

Comment: Yes, but Ordensbrüder are only for men and Krankenpfleger (plural) is for mixed groups.

Comment: @Iris: That was my point, actually. There's no rule in language that wouldn't have all kind of exceptions

Answer (score 1):

*Gebrüder* to me is very specifically only the men of a family and a very “old” word with a specific meaning. *Geschwister* is what I describe my siblings with.

As pointed out [in the question you referenced](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31887/what-is-the-difference-between-br%C3%BCder-and-gebr%C3%BCder) *Gebrüder* is more of a “corporate” term. It quite probably arose from the fact that men used to work and also take over the job of their fathers. Therefore the family and especially its male members were intimately tied to the family's profession. *Gebrüder* is in a way the word for the staff of such a “family-company”.

*Geschwister* on the other hand is simply the word for siblings. Since both words have quite different meaning, *Geschwister* is the only real candidate for siblings.

Comment: Do you mean why *Geschwister* is the word for siblings? I tried to explain why *Gebrüder* is not the same as siblings. I thought that would explain why sibling remained as the only word for sibling. ;)

Comment: It's totally fine! :) I will try to improve my answer. ;)