# Meaning of "Apfelgrütz"

Tags: meaning, noun, regional

In dem berühmten Märchen *Schneewittchen* in der Fassung der Gebrüder Grimm (die es *Sneewittchen* nennen), wird die Szene, in der Schneewittchen schließlich aus ihrem todesgleichen Zustand erwacht, [wie folgt beschrieben](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Grimm,+Jacob+und+Wilhelm/M%C3%A4rchen/Kinder-+und+Hausm%C3%A4rchen/53.+Sneewittchen):

> Der Königssohn ließ ihn [den Sarg] nun von seinen Dienern auf den Schultern forttragen. Da geschah es, daß sie über einen Strauch stolperten, und von dem Schüttern fuhr der giftige Apfelgrütz, den Sneewittchen abgebissen hatte, aus dem Hals.

Wie bitte? Was war das für ein Ding, das Schneewittchen aus dem Hals fuhr?

---

English version:

In the famous fairy tale *Schneewittchen*, as recorded by the Grimm Brothers (who call it *Sneewittchen*), Snow White's final awakening from a quasi-dead state, due to eating from a poisoned apple, [is described as follows](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Grimm,+Jacob+und+Wilhelm/M%C3%A4rchen/Kinder-+und+Hausm%C3%A4rchen/53.+Sneewittchen):

> Der Königssohn ließ ihn [den Sarg] nun von seinen Dienern auf den Schultern forttragen. Da geschah es, daß sie über einen Strauch stolperten, und von dem Schüttern fuhr der giftige Apfelgrütz, den Sneewittchen abgebissen hatte, aus dem Hals.

Say what? What was ejected from Snow White's throat?

Comment: See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCtze) or [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gr%C3%BCtze#1) from which, given the context, I'd say it's partially chewed apple. DWDS also has *Apfelgrutzen* which seems close, but apparently it's more like "apple core".

Comment: **Brüder** Grimm, see https://german.stackexchange.com/q/31887/34192.

Comment: *Apfelgrütz* taucht in den Kommentaren zum Zwiebelfisch-Artikel zum Apfelrest auf: https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-spezial-von-aepfeln-erschlagen-a-331216.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In diesem Zusammenhang bedeutet "Grütz" nichts grob Gemahlenes oder Breiartiges wie das Wort [Grütze](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCtze). Zitat aus dem Märchen:

*Der Apfel war aber so künstlich gemacht, daß der rote Backen allein vergiftet war. Schneewittchen lusterte den schönen Apfel an, und als es sah, daß die Bäuerin davon aß, so konnte es nicht länger widerstehen, streckte die Hand hinaus und nahm die giftige Hälfte. Kaum aber hatte es einen Bissen davon im Mund, so fiel es tot zur Erde nieder. ...*

*... und von dem Schüttern fuhr der giftige Apfelgrütz, den Schneewittchen abgebissen hatte, aus dem Hals.*

Es geht klar hervor, dass Schneewittchen das Apfelstück nicht gekaut und heruntergeschluckt hat, sondern allein durch den Kontakt tot zur Erde fiel. Es handelt sich also um ein unzerkautes Stück Apfel, daher ist "Apfelbissen", "Apfelstück", "Apfelschnitz"  o.ä. eine angemessene Übertragung.

Das Wort "Grütz" ist im Übrigen eine Dialektform für das Kerngehäuse des Apfels, vgl. [hier](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-spezial-von-aepfeln-erschlagen-a-331216.html). Zitate aus dem Artikel:

> Dabei war eine klare Tendenz festzustellen: im Norden und im Osten dominieren die Ableitungen des Wortes Griebs, im Westen sind es Nüssel und Kitsche, in der Mitte Grutze und im Süden Butzen.

> Siegerland: Marzel, Masel, Mäsel, Nesel, Nösel, Gritze, Grütz, Grebs und Gäiz

> Nordhessen: Ich komme aus dem Nordhessischen (Nähe Kassel), und bei uns heisst das Ding Apfelgrütz. Ich war übrigens felsenfest davon überzeugt, dass dies der hochdeutsche Begriff ist. Viele Grüße aus einem mittlerweile in Köln tätigen Nordhessen!

Die Brüder Grimm haben bekanntlich einen Großteil ihrer Märchen im hessischen Dialektraum zusammengetragen und lebten viele Jahre in Kassel (vgl. obiges Zitat).

Die Interpretation "Kerngehäuse" passt allerdings auch nicht wirklich, denn beim Biss in die vergiftete Apfelhälfte hätte Schneewittchen sicher nicht zuerst das nahezu ungenießbare Kerngehäuse in den Mund genommen. Es bleibt also meine oben vorgetragene Erläuterung.

**Ergänzung:**

Henning Kockerbeck weist in einem Kommentar darauf hin, dass "Apfelkrotzen" eine Variante von "Apfelgrütz" ist. In der Frankfurter Gegend wird das als "Abbelkrotze" oder "Äbbelkrotze" ausgesprochen und ist mir bestens bekannt. Der Hinweis auf das Wort "Krotzen" führt auf weitere Bedeutungsnuancen. Das Deutsche Wörterbuch (16 Bände in 32 Teilbänden. Leipzig 1854–1961) von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm [sagt dazu](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Krotzen):

> krotze, krotzen, m. ein westmd. wort, z. b. bei Vilmar 229 hessisch als kernhaus des obstes, kehlkopf und verschrumpftes, verwachsenes obst, letzteres bei Schmidt westerw. id. 92 **allgemeiner 'etwas kleines'**, auch von menschen und thieren, z. b. ein kleiner krotze, ein kleines verschrumpftes kind (in Coblenz krotz f.).

Insofern liegt die Interpretation "ein kleines Stück Apfel" nahe. Das ist übrigens auch in der englischen Übersetzung so:

*For the apple was so cunningly made, that all the poison was in the rosy half of it. Snow-white longed for the beautiful apple, and as she saw the peasant woman eating a piece of it she could no longer refrain, but stretched out her hand and took the poisoned half. But no sooner had she taken a morsel* [= Bissen, Stückchen, Happen] *of it into her mouth than she fell to the earth as dead. ...*

*... and with the shaking the bit of poisoned apple flew out of her throat.*

Comment: [Atlas Alltagssprache](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r11-f1a/?child=runde) verortet Grutz/Grutzen ins Saarland, Rheinland-Pfalz und Hessen. DWB kennt den Ausdruck [Grütz](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=gruetz) in einer Apfel-Variante.

Comment: Eine weitere Variante ist übrigens [Apfelkrotzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Krotzen).

Answer (score 1):

Grütze ist ein alter Begriff für grob gemahlenes Essbares.
Also ist das abgebissene und halb zerkaute Stück Apfel immer noch im Mund oder Hals gewesen und wurde durch die Erschütterungen herausbefördert.

Müsste eigentlich eine Bauchlage voraussetzen oder einen kapitalen Absturz der Transportbox. Aber das ist hier egal.

Getreide-Grütze ist vergleichbar mit Schrot.
Die norddeutsche Rote Grütze ist einigermaßen bekannt, es gibt aber auch grüne oder gelbe Grütze.